# Center the content of div with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this footer:

```
<div id="footer" class="navbar-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12" style="text-align: center;">
        <ul class="menu-footer">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fportfolio.png"><p class="merg-top">Portfolio</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="center" src="images/fabout.png"><p class="merg-top">About</p></a></li>
            <li><img width="160px" src="images/logo.png"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fclients.png"><p class="merg-top">Clients</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fcontact.png"><p class="merg-top">Contact</p></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each text and image are centered perfectly inside the `li` element, now I like the `ul` element reside in center of the div, but its now aligned to left.

Comment: `.menu-footer { width: 200px; margin: 0px auto; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix the width of your `.menu-footer`, and add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to center it on its parent `div`.

Answer (score 2):

centered an item must crush the float property,

Add this css:

```
.span12 {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 <div class="span12 text-center">
    <ul class="menu-footer">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fportfolio.png"><p class="merg-top">Portfolio</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img class="center" src="images/fabout.png"><p class="merg-top">About</p></a></li>
        <li><img width="160px" src="images/logo.png"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fclients.png"><p class="merg-top">Clients</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fcontact.png"><p class="merg-top">Contact</p></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```